# How to get an image's width and height within a for loop in Jekyll Liquid syntax and translate it to a js $variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jekyll, liquid

Would be there a way to define (assign or capture) a variable where I'd be able to get an image's **width** and **height** using Liquid logic? I'd expect to pass those values to a **js** `$variable` later.

Bellow are the steps my site takes until the moment I expect to use the image size values... E.g:

On each .markdown document's front-matter definitions I have a list of associative arrays such as follows:

```
single_module:
  - url: 'anchor-480x480.jpg'
    width: "480"
    height: "480"
    alt: 'An image's alt text'
  - url: 'kart2.jpg'
    width: "1300"
    height: "1300"
    alt: 'An image's alt text'
```

...

On a page's html layout I have a `for loop` which grabs all the values I need from the document's front-matter. At this point I'm translating the **width** and **height** values of each image defined in the front-matter as the `url:` key to a `data-attribute` within the html.

```
{% assign modules = page.single_module %}
{% for module in modules %}
<div class="module default-module" data-bgimage="{{ site.baseurl | prepend: site.project_upload_path }}{{module.url}}" data-width="{{module.width}}" data-height="{{module.height}}">
</div>
```

The above would result in something like:

```
<div data-bgimage="/uploads/projects/anchor-480x480.jpg" data-width="480" data-height="480">
</div>
```

...

From here on I'd expect to use the `data-width` and `data-height` values in the following js function:

The javascript function bellow takes account of images **width** and **height** through an **`$img`** variable. This is not the complete function, it is just the part that uses the `$img` variable, Please see bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var moduleImage = $(".module");
// Create the $img variable
var $img = moduleImage.data("bgimage");

...

ui : {
resizeElement : function($img, h){

// This function resizes a given element over a certain height. It also centers the element...

var maxHeight = h,
maxWidth = $(window).width(),
oldHeight = $img.height(),
oldWidth = $img.width(),
ratio = Math.max(oldWidth / oldHeight, oldHeight / oldWidth),
newHeight = 0,
newWidth = 0;

// Complex calculations to get the perfect size

if(oldWidth > oldHeight){

if ( maxHeight * ratio < maxWidth ) {
newWidth = maxWidth;
newHeight = maxWidth / ratio;
} else {
newHeight = maxHeight;
newWidth = maxHeight * ratio;
}

} else {

if ( maxHeight / ratio < maxWidth ) {
newWidth = maxWidth;
newHeight = maxWidth * ratio;
} else {
newHeight = maxHeight;
newWidth = maxHeight / ratio;
}

}

// Apply the correct size and reposition

$img.css({
'width': Math.ceil(newWidth),
'height': Math.ceil(newHeight),
'top': Math.round((h-newHeight)/2),
'left': Math.round(($(window).width()-newWidth)/2)
});

},

});//end document.ready
```

This seems to go beyond my programming skills as I'm not a dev, but a designer who like to do some coding. Anyway, How in the world could I pass to the js `$img` variable the values from the jekyll for loop syntax stored in the `data-width` and `data-height` attributes.

extracted from the function above, I've tried the following:
...

```
var moduleImage = $(".module");
// Create new offscreen image to test
var $img = moduleImage.data("bgimage");

oldHeight = $img.height(),
oldWidth = $img.width(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already gotten the data into your HTML using Liquid, now (if I understand correctly) you just need to get the data from your HTML DOM into your script. You can get it the same way you're getting the `bgimage`.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
oldHeight = moduleImage.data('height'),
oldWidth = moduleImage.data('width'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this jekyll plugin [jekyll-image-size](https://github.com/generalui/jekyll-image-size). It lets you add liquid tags anywhere in your templates to extract width and height information from local assets and output it in many different formats. For example:

```html
<script>
let {width, height} = {{ imagesize /assets/image.png:json }};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a full-screen background-image. If you are OK with not supporting IE8 you can use the CSS commands background: url('yourimage'), and background-size: cover. That seems like the simplest solution for your problem. Less (code) is more...